# Cannot start mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I have did the mongodb  installation process mentioned in the following link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/ but i can't start the mongodb this is my log kindly tell me the possible way to start mongo db

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe"
2017-03-12T12:42:55.378+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5
400 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=vimals
2017-03-12T12:42:55.379+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/W
indows Server 2008 R2
2017-03-12T12:42:55.380+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.2
2017-03-12T12:42:55.381+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3f76e40c105
fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b
2017-03-12T12:42:55.382+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL
 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
2017-03-12T12:42:55.382+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-03-12T12:42:55.383+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: enterprise
2017-03-12T12:42:55.384+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-03-12T12:42:55.385+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: windows-64
2017-03-12T12:42:55.385+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-03-12T12:42:55.386+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-03-12T12:42:55.387+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-03-12T12:42:55.389+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndList
en: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: C:\data\db\mongod.lock The process canno
t access the file because it is being used by another process.. Is a mongod inst
ance already running?, terminating
2017-03-12T12:42:55.390+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close
 listening sockets...
2017-03-12T12:42:55.390+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush
 diaglog...
2017-03-12T12:42:55.391+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-03-12T12:42:55.392+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:
100
```

Comment: There are two possible options: 1. not sufficient permission to run mongodb  2. Another mongodb process is already running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks as if your database file is locked by another process, did you try restarting the machine?

Answer (score 0):

Just for notes.
In my case, after I create db with:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

I also have to do this:

```
sudo chmod 777 /data/db
```

Then the environment is up for running by entering:

```
mongod
```

to enter the mongoldb shell.